# How to change x and y velocities in response to a wall bounce

Tags: trigonometry, physics, game-development

I 'program' simple hyper casual mobile games in my free time using a sudo programming language software called construct 3, as I am still learning actual languages and can't yet use them well enough to make games.

Essentially I am writing my own super simple bouncing ball physics engine. I have up to 3 balls in this little pinball game of mine at any time. I have given each ball an x velocity and y velocity instance variable.

Here is my question: how do the x and y velocities change when the ball bounces off of a surface with any angle? I know that if the floor is flat and it hits that, x stays the same and y flips it's polarity. I know the opposite happens with hitting a wall. But I have no idea how to calculate any other angle besides the 4 main axes. I'm sure it is a simple trig function. Oh, and dumb your answer down to the most simple sudo-code response you can make.

Answer (score 0):

For any collision of an object against a flat surface of an angle `alpha`, your object will bounce back with an angle `-alpha`. Also, your have what's called a conservation of momentum, which means if your surface doesn't move and does not absorb anything, the total velocity of your object will not change either.

That being said, "all you need to do" is to parameter both the angle of your surface to the horizontal **and** the angle of your object incoming to your surface, so you can easily register an angle `alpha`. This way, you will be able to get a `-alpha` angle between your object and the surface after the collision in the frame of your surface, and you will then need to go back to the "horizontal frame" by simply adding the angle of your surface.

As far as your implementation should go, this is what I suggest:

- Start with a function `horizontalToAngularFrame` that will takes one or more parameter depending if you're in 2D or 3D, so you can define the angle
- Code another function `AngularFrameToHorizontal` with the same number of parameter
- When an object enters in collision, just treat is as you would treat an object in the horizontal frame, and use the 2 previously coded functions to bring the angles back to your horizontal frame